# What patterns and practices of use Entity Framework and DbContext do you know?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, design-patterns, entity-framework-4

I like to use EntityFramework to quickly create sites on the ASP.NET MVC. I usually use the "databae first" principle and DbContext.

I create a global layer that interacts with DbContext and returns, changes, deletes and adds entries. Something like this:

```
GetLastPosts (int count)
FindPostById (int id)
RemovePost (int id)
...
```

All in one class. Usually, it becomes very large and I do not like it. Please tell me about your experience of usage EntityFramework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use the repository pattern with the unit of work pattern:

Here is the best tutorial that I found. It shows how to create both patterns in asp.net, however, the implementation will be the same in any app. It doesn't have to be asp.net

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

And a more general example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx

Answer (score 1):

One pattern I like (I don't know if its even a recognised pattern) is whereby you create extension methods on your DBContext which allows you to load classes that contain queries. This means you can compartmentalise your queries somewhat.

```
public static XTypeQueries XTypeQueries(this EntityModel db)
{
    return new XTypeQueries(db);
}
```

and in a separate file

```
public class XTypeQueries : QueryLibrary
{
    public XTypeQueries (EntityModel db) : base(db) { }

    public IQueryable<Object> DoSomeQuery()
    {
        return from ... in this.db...
               select ...;
    }
}
```

The query library object you're extending from is simply

```
public abstract class QueryLibrary
{
    protected readonly EntityModel db;

    protected QueryLibrary(EntityModel db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }
}
```

The upshot of this is that you can do

```
var query = new EntityModel().XTypeQueries.DoSomeQuery();
```

I try to keep the method as Queryable so that when the methods are called you can be as specific as you need without lots of wasted processing. You now have libraries of queries that are grouped together but act just like you'd written the Linq inline.

Comment: I don't like that you expose IQueryable in your query objects. The reason to make such objecs is to abstaract away a query logic in a component that can be easily mocked in unit tests. When exposing IQueryable you make those abstraction leaky.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I think you need to create a separate database layer, and you will need many domain classes rather then a single class, which will do operations like create, update and delete on database entities just like the [Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx).

For example to do operations related to `client` you will need `ClientRepository` class.

```
var clientRepo = new ClientRepository();
clientRepo.AddClient(Client clientEntity);
List<Client> clientDM = clientRepo.GetClients(23);
```

Comment: Your code sample is a total mess. I'm not sure what it does in any line, what those methods return, what side effects they have.

Comment: Here the idea is important, not the actual implementation. The code here is to tell that you need domain entities which will handle the operations of insertion, deletion and update.

Comment: Then the idea is also wrong. Entities should not carry the responsibility of persisting themselves. That's the role of a repository.

Comment: Yes you are right that is not the job of entities, that's why I am suggesting domain entities just like repository pattern to do that job. My point is that I would not be a single classes but many class unlike described in the question.